# Plt imshow didn't automatically deals with negative value (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm currently implementing Difference of Gaussian algorithm. So far I've managed to create the DoG in each octave and form the pyramid. First all image is already in greyscale, second We know that each image in each DoG level is created by subtracting the current image with the previous image (this will result with some negative values).

Now I want to plot this using matplotlib. From the documentation, I read "imshow automatically deals with negative values by scaling the lightness values appropriately, so the smallest (negative) values will be displayed black, the values close to zero will be gray, and the highest values will be white." so I try it like this

`plt.imshow(imae, cmap="gray")`

but somehow I still got the greyscale image instead of black and white like in some example here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/10/detailed-guide-powerful-sift-technique-image-matching-python/

Then I tried to set the vmin to zero and it works. I just don't understand why didn't It behave as stated in the documentation by default

** **EDIT (included some source code)** **

This is what my DoG octave look like

```
def DoG_octave(gaussian_octave):
    octave = []
    for i in range(0, len(gaussian_octave)-1):
      next_image = np.subtract(gaussian_octave[i+1], gaussian_octave[i])
      octave.append(next_image)

    return octave
```

This will take one gaussian octave level from the gaussian pyramid and return also one level of DoG octave to create the DoG pyramid, and for each image in this level ('imae'), I display them using imshow, hence
`plt.imshow(imae, cmap="gray")`

Comment: This often happens when you have outliers lets say some value in the image is -3, and some other is 10 and the rest is ~0. In that case most parts of the image becomes grey-ish. Without more information about your variable `imae`, it is difficult to help you further.

Comment: @LudvigH May i ask what should i provide more with variable `imae`?

Comment: Make a MVE that shows your problem. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @LudvigH i hope it sufficient enough